# MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR (not logged in) Redemption (using Outlook not MAPI standalone)

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have got my application working fine with the standalone MAPI (1.2.1 CDO) however after removing that and installing Outlook, I cannot get it working.

I get a MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR, which when I catch and return the exception message caught comes up with

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Not logged on. Please log on first
```

Do I have to do anything different to get this working with an outlook installation? This is thrown when doing

```
LogonExchangeMailbox(username, exserver)
```

Comment: What version of Exchange are you connecting to?

Comment: Sorry should have included that - it's 2010.

Answer (score 1):

MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR is a network access error. Is firewall active on that machine? Was your app added to the exclusion list?

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the name of the exchange server not being correct. I had this issue as the old exchange server had been decommissioned so rather than being EXHANGE.ad.{company}.com it changed to just the new server name e.g. EXCHANGEABC12.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that `LogonExchangeMailbox` connect using plain old RPC protocol. If you are connecting to Exchange 2013/2016 over RPC-over-HTTP, you need to use `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` .